# Parsing Text Data with Dynamic Structure(Table) in C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where users can upload text data that doesn't have a fixed structure. The challenge I'm facing is how to parse this dynamic text data and store it in a way that allows for flexible handling of columns and values.

Here's a simplified example of the text data:

[See image to see text sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQsjU.png)

The columns and their structure are not fixed, and the spaces between values are variable. I want to dynamically parse this data and store it in a way that I can work with it without having a predefined model.

I've tried using regular expressions and dictionaries, but I'm facing challenges with detecting columns accurately and handling variable spaces.

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem and if there are better strategies for parsing and handling dynamic text data in C# ASP.NET Core.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You gave the sample as a. picture and not as a text, thus it makes it harder to predict. I would assume with a monospaced font, all those columns line up precisely. If it is the case then it would be a SDF (system data format) or FWD (Fixed width data) which is easy to parse. From the header line you would calculate the column widths and parse the rest based on it, that is all.

Comment: It would be nicer if you would have been share your current implementation, however, parsing dynamic text data in ASP.NET Core requires flexibility. You could utilize powerful libraries like CSVHelper, write custom parsing logic, or use regular expressions to extract data. Store parsed data in dictionaries, dynamic objects, or custom classes. Consider error handling, validation, and performance optimization. Actually it completly depends on your existing scenario and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would just take a few lines of the data, and paste into notepad, or your favorite text editor.

That data looks to be fixed width, and thus quite much a standard type of text import that we developers have add to deal with at some point in time.

In fact, I'm still a real ace with MS-Access, and it's text import wizard is rather handy to get the column start/end for each column.

Hence this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Of course, you did NOT paste the sample data as text, so you forced me to have to open up note pad, and type in some sample data. Too bad, since I would have easily determined the column start/end for each of the columns. Anyway, you have to simple determine the column start/end of the data, as it will be what we called a fixed text import.

So, assuming this SQL server table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyItems](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SNo] [int] NULL,
        [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Qty] [int] NULL,
        [Rate] [money] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

So, to parse this data, the code will be much like this:

```
    protected void cmdParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Myitems WHERE ID = 0";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL); 
        DataTable rstItems = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);

        string sData = txtData.Text;  // this is our text file input
        string[] sParse;
        sParse = sData.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None);

        int LineCount = 0;
        foreach (string OneLine in sParse) 
        { 
            LineCount++;
            if (LineCount > 0)
            {
                if (OneLine.Trim().Length > 0)  // skip blank lines
                {
                    DataRow NewRecord = rstItems.NewRow();
                    NewRecord["Sno"] = Convert.ToInt32(OneLine.Substring(0, 6).Trim());
                    NewRecord["Description"] = OneLine.Substring(22, 60).Trim();
                    NewRecord["Qty"] = Convert.ToInt32(OneLine.Substring(87, 4).Trim());
                    NewRecord["Rate"] = decimal.Parse(OneLine.Substring(103,12).Trim(),NumberStyles.Currency);
                    rstItems.Rows.Add(NewRecord);   
                }
            }
        }

        // save all rows added to database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);  
            conn.Open();
            da.Update(rstItems);
        }
    }
```